# how to evaluate java function using __groovy and assign it as part of Http Request

Tags: api, spring-boot, groovy, jmeter

I have a http request with the following structure.
Http Request :-

```
"Accounts": [
      {
        "accountType": "SAVINGS",
        "RefNumber": "${RefNumber}",
        "accountNo": "${AccNumber}"
      }
    ],
"encryptionKey": "${__groovy(new com.util.EncryptUtil().encrypt(), encryptedValue)}"
```

The value of `encryptionKey` is calculated using the mentioned groovy function. The encrypt function takes the Accounts object and calculates the encryptedValue based on the value of `RefNumber` and `accountNo`. The value of `accountNo` comes from the first Http Response API. The value of the `RefNumber` comes from the second Http Response API. How do I accept the dynamic Accounts object `json` and calculate the encrypted value in `jmeter` and how do I check if the function result is being assigned to `encryptionKey` using jmeter?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can check your function output using [The Function Helper Dialog](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper)

Example class I use for demo looks like:

```
package com.util;

public class EncryptUtil {

    public String encrypt() {
        return "some encrypted value";
    }
}
```

[image]

Second, you can check your request payload using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

[image]

And finally you can check generated `${encryptedValue}` variable using [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/)

[image]